# Convert a python list to string (the list includes some strings)

Tags: python, string, list

I hope to convert a list of strings to a list of a long string. For example, I hope to convert ['c++', 'python', 'sklearn', 'java'] to ["'c++', 'python', 'sklearn', 'java'"]. Namely, the original list have some strings, the target list should have a long string which includes the small string.

I have tried the  ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in s]), but the results are not in a list.

```
s = ['c++', 'python', 'sklearn', 'java']
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in s])
print listToStr
```

The expected output is:

```
["'c++', 'python', 'sklearn', 'java'"]
```

The actual output is:

```
c++ python sklearn java
```

Comment: I can't resist asking why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join it with commas, add the single quotes and put it in a list:

```
myList= [", ".join(["'"+elem+"'" for elem in s])]
```

Comment: I believe it should be `", ".join...` based on his question.

Comment: thanks, it should add the single quote and add "," before join.

Comment: Not creating the inner list and using `.format` would be much more efficient. It also removes the burden of doing `str(elem)` (which I'm not sure why you did. Inputs are clearly strings) `[", ".join("'{}'".format(elem) for elem in s)]`

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using one line of code and no loop/join by turning the list to a string and taking the brackets off. Then wrap it in a list.

```
print [str(s)[1:-1]]
```